# How to pre-evaluate condition before accepting GET/POST request in Java Spring Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have written a class to find out the amount of free memory using *Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()* The class having the structure:

```
public class MemoryInfo 
{

private final long FREE_MEMORY = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

public long getFreeMemory() {
    return this.FREE_MEMORY;
 }
```

Another class is written to accept POST requests, and it is needed to be ensured that requests are accepted only if this free memory is above some threshold. How to ensure this? The application is hosted on CloudFoundry.

EDIT : The other class

```
 @Controller
public class StudentRegisterController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register/student")
    @ResponseBody
    StudentRegistrationReply registerStudent(@RequestBody StudentRegistration studentregd)  {
    StudentRegistrationReply stdregreply = new StudentRegistrationReply();
    MemoryInfo meminfo = new MemoryInfo();
    stdregreply.setName(studentregd.getName());
    stdregreply.setAge(studentregd.getAge());
    stdregreply.setRegistrationNumber("12345678");
    stdregreply.setRegistrationStatus("Successful");
    return stdregreply;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the other class , the one that accepts the post requests?

Comment: edited the post. check now

Comment: can you not add the condition inside your `registerStudent` method.

Comment: No, in that case the request would already reach the system (through the argument). The check needs to be done before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a Handler Interceptor.

```
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler) throws Exception {

        return Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() > anumber;
    }

}
```

and define it in you WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer  {
     @Override
     public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
           registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/register/student");

     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this looks helpful,  but I am not being able to make this work. Can you tell me what else should I do other than these two?

Comment: what do you mean by "I am not being able to make this work" ? Is the preHandle method executed when you POST /register/student ?

Comment: No, instead the function registerStudent is getting executed.

Comment: do you have a WebMvcConfigurer ?

Comment: I made an MvcConfigurer implementing the WebMvcConfigurer interface, and overrided the "addInterceptors" method, as in your answer. What further?

Comment: that should be enough. Is your MvcConfigurer annotated with "@Configuration" and "@EnableWebMvc" ?

Comment: Was not. So I added them, but now throwing 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178679/discussion-between-e-g78-and-dhrubojit).